# cron job gives me permission denied errors when running

Tags: cron

Been trying to run a cron but keep getting permission died error in my `/var/spool/mail/root`

```
"/bin/sh: /disk1/archives/backup.website.cron: Permission denied"
```

This is my `ls -hal` for the directory my cron jobs are in

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Feb  6 04:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Feb  5 08:14 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  105 Feb  6 04:22 backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  102 Feb  5 08:34 backup.database.cron
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   75 Feb  5 08:33 backup.website.cron
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb  5 08:35 databases
```

I have `backup` set to `chmod +x`

The backup file looks like this

```
* * * * *  root /disk1/archives/backup.website.cron
30 * * * * root /disk1/archives/backup.database.cron
```

I ran the cron with

`crontab /disk/1/archives/backup`

I can see that my cron jobs are set up to run because when I do  `crontab -l` I get

```
[root@web archives]# crontab -l
* * * * * /disk1/archives/backup.website.cron
30 * * * * /disk1/archives/backup.database.cron
```

backup.website.cron looks like

```
tar -zcvf /disk1/archives/websites/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%I:%M:%S%p`.tar.gz /web
```

while backup.website.cron looks like

```
mysqldump --opt --all-databases | gzip > /disk1/archives/databases/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%I:%M:%S%p`.sql.gz
```

am i missing a permission change somewhere?

am i running the correct scripts thru the crontab?

Comment: is there /web ? and also please replace commands with full path since cron runs in limited PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chmod +x /disk1/archives/backup.*.cron
```

The file that you feed to `crontab` command doesn't need to be executable, since it isn't a shell script.  Any commands that you invoke as cron jobs *do* need to be executable.

There's another oddity here.  There are two slightly different syntaxes for crontab.  One has 5 fields that specify when the command is to be executed, followed by the command itself; this is the format that the `crontab` command expects.  The other adds a username between the 5 time fields and the command.  This is the format used by `/etc/crontab`, and by files under the `/etc/cron.*` directories.  (That's on Ubuntu 11.04; the organization might differ slightly on other systems.)

You said you installed your `backup` file with `crontab /disk/1/archives/backup`, but the `backup` file you showed us specifies the `root` user on each line.  But your `crontab -l` output doesn't show the `root` user name.

The error message you're getting is consistent with the `crontab -l` output (if the file you gave to `crontab` had the `root` username, it would attempt to execute `root` as a command).  I presume the actual file you fed to `crontab` doesn't have the `root` fields.

`man 5 crontab` for information about the difference between normal and system cron files.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, your right. i got 2 clipboards confused when i pasted. The crontab doesn't have the root issued. So you are are saying that I need to chmod +x the backup.*.cron rather than the backup file that has the cron job rules.